# How can I add an author + number pair to a text file with my discord bot, and then add consecutive numbers after?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot that can take in commands and store info in text files.
My goal is to have different items that people can add numbers to and then check their totals for each item.

For example, if I did !add 200 oranges, the bot would add the number 200 with the user id to the oranges.txt file. I would have different files for each item. If I then did !add 300 oranges, the number next to the user id with be 500. I would then want to let a user check their totals.

right now I have this:

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def loot(ctx, num, kind):
    author = str(ctx.message.author)
    message = list()
    message.append(num)
    message.append(kind)
    #below line for testing
    await bot.say(message)
```

The code takes in the number and name of the item, then creates a list [num, item]. My idea is then to use message[1] to find which text file to input in, and then somehow add message[0] with the author variable which is the user id to a list, but at that point im lost. I dont know how to add an author id + number, add to the number, and then retrieve it.

If you need any clarification please ask!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a job for a DBMS. Check out https://www.sqlite.org/, or do some research and pick another one. It allows for a structured way to store data, and eliminates these kinds of problems.

Sorry if this does answer your actual question, but there is an easier solution to the problem you are having. Storing data like this in text files is widely regarded as bad practice (not even taking into account what kind of security problems this can yield.)

Comment: Would it be easier to store it in an excel spreadsheet? Security isnt an issue.

Comment: An excel spreadsheet is still just a text file. Like I said, use a DBMS.